# TextClassifierImpl: Error suggesting selection for text. No changes to selection suggested. FileNotFoundException: No file for null locale

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http, textview

I have an application that sends a relatively long Get request.
Here is the thing, when the Get Request isn't really long, it works perfectly fine, when the Get request Contains a lot of data it crashes the application...
I truly have no idea why, and I can't really understand the cause of the crash.
this is my Asynctask:

```
public class CreatePostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, CreatePostData> {


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    p5= ProgressDialog.show(CreatePostActivity.this,"checks data",getString(R.string.loadingPleaseWait),true);
    p5.setCancelable(true);
    p5.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    p5.setMessage(getString(R.string.loadingDotDotDot));
    p5.show();

}

@Override
protected CreatePostData doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String str=params[0];
    String res=performCreatePostCall(str);
    Log.d("ress", res);
    CreatePostData regi = null;
    String Response = params[0];
    if (Response.matches(""))
    {
        regi = new CreatePostData("null", "null");
    }
    else {
        try {

            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(res);
            String Status = json_data.getString("status");
            String error = "null";
            if (Status.equals("ok"))
                error = "null";
            else
                error= json_data.getString("error");
            Log.d("coo", error);
            regi = new CreatePostData(Status, error);
            Log.d("stat", regi.getStatus());
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
        Log.d("aa", res);
    }
    return regi;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(CreatePostData result) {
    Log.d("stat2", result.getStatus());

    if (result.getStatus().equals("ok")) {
        p5.dismiss();
        onBackPressed();
    }
    else if(result.getError().equals("Username already exists."))
    {
        Toast.makeText(CreatePostActivity.this, R.string.UserNameIsAlreadyCaught, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else if(result.getError().equals("E-mail address is already in use"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(CreatePostActivity.this, R.string.EmailIsAlreadyCaught, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("Didit", result.getError());
        Toast.makeText(CreatePostActivity.this, R.string.UnknownErrorCloseAndTryAgain, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (p5.isShowing()){
        p5.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

this is the "performCreatePostCall" class:

```
public String performCreatePostCall(String requestURL) {

URL url;
Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 1");
String response = "";
try {
    Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 2");
    url = new URL(requestURL);
    Log.d("nugi", url.toString());

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.d("status3", String.valueOf(responseCode));
    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 3");
        String line;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"));
        Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 4");
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
            Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 5");
        }
        Log.d("nugi", response);

    }
    else {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream(), "iso-8859-1"));
        Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 4");
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
            Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 5");
        }
        Log.d("nugi", response);

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return response;
}
```

and below is logcat Error:

```
03-01 08:32:19.291 15137-15194/com.example.negev.peulibraryv201 E/TextClassifierImpl: Error suggesting selection for text. No changes to selection suggested.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No file for null locale
        at android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifierImpl.getSmartSelection(TextClassifierImpl.java:196)
        at android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifierImpl.suggestSelection(TextClassifierImpl.java:104)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationHelper.suggestSelection(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:650)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.-android_widget_SelectionActionModeHelper-mthref-0(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:88)
        at android.widget.-$Lambda$tTszxdFZ0V9nXhnBpPsqeBMO0fw$1.$m$1(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.widget.-$Lambda$tTszxdFZ0V9nXhnBpPsqeBMO0fw$1.get(Unknown Source:16)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationAsyncTask.doInBackground(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:565)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationAsyncTask.doInBackground(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:560)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
03-01 08:32:19.292 15137-15194/com.example.negev.peulibraryv201 E/TextClassifierImpl: Error getting assist info.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No file for null locale
        at android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifierImpl.getSmartSelection(TextClassifierImpl.java:196)
        at android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifierImpl.classifyText(TextClassifierImpl.java:150)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationHelper.performClassification(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:688)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationHelper.suggestSelection(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:654)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.-android_widget_SelectionActionModeHelper-mthref-0(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:88)
        at android.widget.-$Lambda$tTszxdFZ0V9nXhnBpPsqeBMO0fw$1.$m$1(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.widget.-$Lambda$tTszxdFZ0V9nXhnBpPsqeBMO0fw$1.get(Unknown Source:16)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationAsyncTask.doInBackground(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:565)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationAsyncTask.doInBackground(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:560)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

What do you think could possibly be the cause?
Thank you!

Comment: You mean: your app crashes when a request takes very long time, not necessarily the whole of Android Studio, correct?

Comment: have u tried using retrofit? you dont have to go thru all this pain. http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Yeah, only the app crashes, my bad...

Comment: the log says `FileNotFoundException: No file for null locale`. It seems you're trying to get a file which is not available?

Comment: it only does that when the request is too long, I wonder why...

Comment: You need to look for the Lifecycle call methods because, you ar calling onBackpressed. and for FileNotFoundException: No file for null locale it states that your request inputstream is null. Check these constraints

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exception when the user double-taps the text in an EditText field, only on Android Oreo 8.1 (API level 27).

Notice the exception comes from `TextClassifierImpl.getSmartSelection`, in an AsyncTask that's trying to classify the selected text in a TextView or EditText view. Your large HTTP request seems to be incidental unless that somehow causes the text selection. None of your code or the HTTP library code is on the stack.

You can prevent the error by adding this code to the Activity `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method:

```java
    // Workaround an Android bug where double-clicking the alarmPeriod EditText field would
    // cause the following log errors:
    //
    // TextClassifierImpl: Error suggesting selection for text. No changes to selection suggested.
    //   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No file for null locale
    //       at android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifierImpl.getSmartSelection(TextClassifierImpl.java:208)
    //       ...
    // TextClassifierImpl: Error getting assist info.
    //   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No file for null locale
    //       at android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifierImpl.getSmartSelection(TextClassifierImpl.java:208)
    //       ...
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 27) {
        myEditTextView.setTextClassifier(TextClassifier.NO_OP);
    }
```